# Changing parts of arrays/structs/.. in threads without blocking the whole thing, in pure c

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I want to modify some (not all) fields of an array (or structs) in multiple threads, with out blocking the rest of the array as the rest of it is being modified in other threads. How is this achieved? I found some answers, but they are for C++ and I want to do it in C.
Here is the code I got so far:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define ARRAYLENGTH 5
#define TARGET 10000

int target;

typedef struct zstr{
    int* array;
    int place;
    int run;
    pthread_mutex_t* locks;
}zstr;

void *countup(void *);

int main(int argc, char** args){
    int al;
    if(argc>2){
        al=atoi(args[1]);
        target=atoi(args[2]);
    }else{
        al=ARRAYLENGTH;
        target=TARGET;
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", al, target);
    zstr* t=malloc(sizeof(zstr));
    t->array=calloc(al, sizeof(int));
    t->locks=calloc(al, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    int* rua=calloc(al, sizeof(int));
    pthread_t id[4*al];
    for(int i=0; i<al; i++)
            pthread_mutex_init(&(t->locks[i]), NULL);
    for(int j=0; j<4*al; j++){
        int st=j%al;
        t->run=rua[st]++;
        t->place=st;
        pthread_create(&id[j], NULL, &countup, t);
    }
    for(int k=0; k<4*al; k++){
        pthread_join(id[k], NULL);
    }
    for(int u=0; u<al; u++)
           printf("%d\n", t->array[u]);
    free(rua);
    free(t->locks);
    free(t->array);
    return 0;
}

void *countup(void* table){
    zstr* nu=table;
    if(!nu->run){
        pthread_mutex_lock(nu->locks + nu->place);
    }else{
        pthread_mutex_trylock(nu->locks + nu->place);
    }
    while(nu->array[nu->place]<target)
        nu->array[nu->place]++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(nu->locks + nu->place); 
    return NULL;
}
```

Sometimes this works just fine, but then calculates wrong values and for quiet sort problems (like the default values), it takes super long (strangely it worked once when I handed them in as parameters).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything special about part of an array or structure. What matters is that the mutex or other synchronization you apply to a given value is used correctly.

In this case, it seems like you're not checking your locking function results.

The design of the countup function only allows a single thread to ever access the object, running the value all the way up to target before releasing the lock, but you don't check the trylock result.

So what's probably happening is the first thread gets the lock, and subsequent threads on the same mutex call trylock and fail to get the lock, but the code doesn't check the result.  Then you get multiple threads incrementing the same value without synchronization.  Given all the pointer dereferences the index and increment operations are not guaranteed to be atomic, leading to problems where the values grow well beyond target.

The moral of the story is to check function results and handle errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply: I wrote the result of the look-function (both normal and try) into a variable int relax and check !relax before increasing the fields and extracted some pointers (like the array) to temp pointers to boost speed, and seemed to worked a little bit, but the malfunctions still occur.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't have enough reputation to comment, yet.

Adding to Brad's comment of not checking the result of `pthread_mutex_trylock`, there's a misconception that shows many times with Pthreads:
You assume, that `pthread_create` will start immediately, and receive the values passed (here pointer `t` to your struct) and it's content read atomically. That is not true. The thread might start any time later and will find the contents, like `t->run` and `t->place` already changed by the next iteration of the j-loop in `main`.

Moreover, you might want to read David Butenhof's book "Programming with Posix Threads" (old, but still a good reference) and check on synchronization and condition variables.

It's not that good style to start that many threads in the first place ;)

As this has come up a few times and might come up again, I have restructured that a bit to issue work_items to the started threads. The code below might be amended by a function, that maps the index into `array` to always the same `area_lock`, or by adding a queue to feed the running threads with further work-item...

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

/*
 * Macros for default values. To make it more interesting, set:
 *    ARRAYLENGTH != THREADS
 *    INCREMENTS != TARGET
 *    NUM_AREAS != THREADS
 * Please note, that NUM_AREAS must be <= ARRAY_LENGTH.
 */
#define ARRAYLENGTH 10
#define TARGET 100
#define INCREMENTS 10
#define NUM_AREAS 2
#define THREADS 5


/* These variables are initialized once in main, then only read... */
int array_len;
int target;
int num_areas;
int threads;
int increments;

/**
 * A long array that is going to be equally split into number of areas.
 * Each area is covered by a lock. The number of areas do not have to
 * equal the length of the array, but must be smaller...
 */
typedef struct shared_array {
    int * array;
    int num_areas;
    pthread_mutex_t * area_locks;
} shared_array;

/**
 * A work-item a thread is assigned to upon startup (or later on).
 * Then a value of { 0, any } might signal the ending of this thread.
 * The thread is working on index within zstr->array, counting up increments
 * (or up until the target is reached).
 */
typedef struct work_item {
    shared_array * zstr;
    int work_on_index;
    int increments;
} work_item;


/* Local function declarations */
void * countup(void *);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int i;
    shared_array * zstr;

    if (argc == 1) {
        array_len = ARRAYLENGTH;
        target = TARGET;
        num_areas = NUM_AREAS;
        threads = THREADS;
        increments = INCREMENTS;
    } else if (argc == 6) {
        array_len = atoi(argv[1]);
        target = atoi(argv[2]);
        num_areas = atoi(argv[3]);
        threads = atoi(argv[4]);
        increments = atoi(argv[5]);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: %s len target areas threads increments", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    assert(array_len >= num_areas);

    zstr = malloc(sizeof (shared_array));
    zstr->array = calloc(array_len, sizeof (int));
    zstr->num_areas = num_areas;
    zstr->area_locks = calloc(num_areas, sizeof (pthread_mutex_t));

    for (i = 0; i < num_areas; i++)
        pthread_mutex_init(&(zstr->area_locks[i]), NULL);

    pthread_t * id = calloc(threads, sizeof (pthread_t));
    work_item * work_items = calloc(threads, sizeof (work_item));

    for (i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        work_items[i].zstr = zstr;
        work_items[i].work_on_index = i % array_len;
        work_items[i].increments = increments;
        pthread_create(&(id[i]), NULL, &countup, &(work_items[i]));
    }
    // Let's just do this one work-item.
    for (i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(id[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("Array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < array_len; i++)
        printf("%d ", zstr->array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    free(id);
    free(work_items);
    free(zstr->area_locks);
    free(zstr->array);
    return 0;
}

void *countup(void* first_work_item) {
    work_item * wi = first_work_item;
    int inc;

    // Extract the information from this work-item.
    int idx = wi->work_on_index;
    int area = idx % wi->zstr->num_areas;
    pthread_mutex_t * lock = &(wi->zstr->area_locks[area]);

    pthread_mutex_lock(lock);
    for (inc = wi->increments; inc > 0 && wi->zstr->array[idx] < target; inc--)
        wi->zstr->array[idx]++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(lock);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Why this? "ARRAYLENGTH != THREADS
 *    INCREMENTS != TARGET
 *    NUM_AREAS != THREADS" I runner you code and non of the fileds reached 100, 5 stayed as 0.

Comment: As the C-comment says: this is to make it more interesting: Potentially, the array could be large ; much larger than the thread-count (in contrast to Your code, where an index was changed by one thread, each). The number of areas, this array is split in may be different than the number of threads, too.
Also, to make it more interesting, the increments should not be of size TARGET, just to show, that multiple threads need to increment an index to reach TARGET.

Your question was: "Changing parts of arrays/structs/.. in threads without blocking the whole thing". That's what my code does.